# Receiving either "list index out of range" or "unsupported operand type(s)" errors for what should be a simple block of code

Tags: python

everyone - this is actually my first post on Stack Overflow, so it's nice to finally be part of the community versus me trawling through old posts to solve homework problems!

I'm trying to learn Python as quarantine has landed me with more free-time than I anticipated, but I'm hitting a very odd snag that I don't properly understand.

The prompt is simple - make a function, add_numbers, that will add two arguments together and return them. I then have to make a call to that function inside of the code (functions.py) so that the learning program I'm using can check my work.

My code is this (not shown is the "import sys" at the top of the file):

```
def add_numbers(num1,num2):
    sum = {num1} + {num2}
    return sum
    
maths = add_numbers(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
print(maths)
```

When I leave it like this, I get an error that says "list index out of range", but if I make it instead

```
maths = add_numbers(sys.argv[0],sys.argv[1])
```

I instead get an error that reads "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'set'". I am very confused as to what this error means, let alone why this is happening. I'm fairly certain that if I were attempt to do something very similar in structure to this in C++, I would have no issue - so why is Python throwing one at me now?

Comment: You are trying to add two sets: `{num1} + {num2}`. Just don't make them sets

Comment: The `list index out of range` is because indexing in Python starts from 0. so if you have two arguments `sys.argv[0]` and `sys.argv[1]` give the first and second arguments. `sys.argv[2]` gives the third argument. So if you only have two arguments you will get `list index out of range`

Comment: As to your index error, how are you running the script? It implies you are only passing one argument. `sys.argv[0]` should be the name of the script

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I removed the {} around both num1 and num2 to un-set-ify them (that was my error), but now I'm getting another list index error.

I'm running the script through Windows PowerShell, I have Python 3 installed on my computer

Comment: you need to provide a [mcve] *How are you running the script?* Have you tried to do any basic debugging? `print(sys.argv)` seems like a natural first step. And when I ask how, I mean the *exact* command you are running on the shell.

Answer (score 0):

The addition part of the code inside the function `add_numbers` should be like this `num1 + num2` without the `{}` characters.

As for the sys.argv related query, when you run a python program from the command line, the first argument or sys.argv[0] is `file_name` and thereon you have the other arguments passed

Edit:

Also, you need to typecase your inputs into int or float before adding up like this

`maths = add_numbers(int(sys.argv[1]),int(sys.argv[2]))`

Comment: I followed your instructions, and it did clear some things up, but there is a *but*. First, when I run the code in PowerShell, I don't get an expected "3", but rather I get "12", which means my code is just smashing num1 and num2 together rather than actually *adding* them. Second of all, the learning program I'm using swears up and down that I'm still having a list error, which I don't understand because I can run my code fine.

Comment: @DanielO'Dette because `sy.arv` is a *list of strings* and `+` concatenates strings. What is the learning program you are using?

Comment: TwilioQuest - I'm shotgunning learning programs in a desperate attempt to learn Python and so far it seems I'm failing. The prompt does want me to actually add the two together so I've screwed up somewhere down the line

Comment: @DanielO'Dette you need to typecast the string into int by doing this `maths = add_numbers(int(sys.argv[1]),int(sys.argv[2]))
`

Comment: Thank you, that worked in PowerShell. TwilioQuest refuses to believe I've actually got a functional program, the error.txt it produces continues to read that there's a list error, but that might be fixed with a restart. As a related question, is there any way to directly input a int argument, or will I need to use int(sys.argv[1]) in all cases where I want an int out of an input?

Comment: I'm not aware of TwilioQuest but if you want to dynamically pass a number instead of hardcoding then you'll need to take it dynamically from the input by `sys.argv[1]` and typecase to  int `int(sys.argv[1])` or to typecase to float use `float(sys.argv[1])`